# Hibernate Inheritance mapping issue

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, inheritance, polymorphism

So, after several attempts of trying and trying to make this work the way I want, and of course checking different guide, I now come to you guys.

My program is designed to work like this:

persona (the father object)
-persona_cuil (pk on DB, generated by user)

empleado (persona's son)
-legajo_id (pk on DB, generated by program NOT DB (couldnt make that work either))
-persona_cuil (FK from persona)

empvarios (empleado's son)
-legajo_id (PK and FK from empleado)

Now, the database is mapped that way, and it works just fine, the problem seems to be that hibernate somewhere mixes the primary keys sent to each object, and instead of inserting a legajo_id in empvarios, it inserts a persona_cuil.

Code for clases:

persona:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class persona implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2847733720742959767L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="persona_cuil")
    private String persona_cuil;
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name="apellido")
    private String apellido;
    @Column(name="fecha_nac")
    private String fecha_nac;
    @Column(name="direccion")
    private String direccion;
    @Column(name="localidad")
    private String localidad;
    @Column(name="provincia")
    private String provincia;
    @Column(name="pais")
    private String pais;
    @Column(name="fecha_muerte")
    private String fecha_muerte;
    @Column(name="fecha_alta")
    private String fecha_alta;
    @Column(name="fecha_baja")
    private String fecha_baja;
    @Column(name="mail")
    private String mail;
    @Column(name="plan_id")
    private int plan_id;

    public persona (){
        this.setPlan_id(0);
    }
//Getters and Setters
}
```

empleado:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empleado")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="persona_cuil")
public class empleado extends persona implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7792000781951823557L;

    @Column(name="legajo_id")
    private int legajo_id;

    public empleado(){
        super();
        int leg = SentenceManager.ultimoRegistro("empleado");
        if (leg == 0){ //this works fine, it just searches the last registry, if it exists, i uses the next available number
            this.setLegajo_id(1);
        }
        else {
            this.setLegajo_id(leg+1);
        }
    }
//Getters and Setters
}
```

empvarios:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="empvarios")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="legajo_id")
public class empvarios extends empleado implements Serializable, ToPersona{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6327388765162454657L;

    @Column(name="ocupacion_id")
    int ocupacion_id;

    public empvarios() {
        super();
        this.setLegajo_id(super.getLegajo_id());
    }
//Getters and setters
}
```

Now, if I try to insert a new empleado into the database, it works just fine... BUT if I try to insert an empvarios, in the place where should be legajo_id, hibernate places the persona_cuil (I tested this by removing the FK restriction on the data base)

Images below:
(cant post images due reputation restriction :/)
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mu5c797adlf7jiv/AACnd8mx7GriSyq5OMKoddRna?dl=0
There you have the 3 photos, the name of the files shows which table is each one.

Any ideas on whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the data base was wrongly mapped.

If anyone has this problem then you will have to rethink the structure of the DB.

As seen in the example i gave above, the database should look like this:

```
persona:
persona_id  (PK-autoincemental)

empleado:
persona_id (FK to persona)
legajo_id

empvarios:
persona_id (FK to persona)
ocupacion_id
```

The reason this works like this is because you cannot have different ids to depend different clases within the data base. On the program side it "can" work like that, but it the data base it has to be mapped differently.

Thanks!